# Moving files to another class and cannot get an overriden method working

Tags: java

I am having to refactor a couple of classes within a project and have a question on how to fix an override problem.

I have a class called `AccSysChannel` that inherits from another class called `SwitchChannel` and has a method called `blockUntilGetMessageLength()` that is denoted with a `@Override` (code below).

`SwitchChannel` used to have a method called `blockUntilGetMessageLength()` and that I had to move to a new class called `ActiveSocket`.

My problem now is that I do not know how to `@Override` `blockUntilGetMessageLength()` in `AccSysChannel` with the method that is now in `ActiveSocket`.  The `AccSysChannel` still must maintain its inheritance from the `SwitchChanne`l because of numerous other methods contained in the `AccSysChannel class.

My question is how can I fix the `@Override` issue?  Hope this makes sense.  Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my `blockUntilGetMessageLength()` in `AccSysChannel`:

```
....

@Override
protected int blockUntilGetMessageLength() {
    byte[] b = new byte[2];
    byte[] other = new byte[14];
    int size = -1;
    String otherStr;

    try {
        Iterator<ActiveSocket> it = activeSockets.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ActiveSocket activeSocket = it.next();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = activeSocket.getDataInputStream(); 
            if (dataInputStream.markSupported()) {
                while (size == -1) {
                    dataInputStream.mark(14);
                    dataInputStream.readFully(other, 0, 14);
                    dataInputStream.reset();
                    otherStr = new String(other);
                    LOGGER.trace("Checking slice of the message: " + otherStr);
                    size = otherStr.indexOf("<AT");
                    if (size == -1){
                        size = otherStr.indexOf("<DSCREDIT");
                    }
                    LOGGER.trace("Found tag at index: " + size);
                    switch (size) {
                        case 0:
                        case 1:
                            // intentional fallthrough
                        case -1:
                            if (size == 0 || size == 1) {
                                size = -1;
                            }
                            dataInputStream.readFully(other, 0, 10);
                            break;
                        default:
                            // consume the bytes preceding the size bytes
                            dataInputStream.readFully(other, 0, size - 2);
                            // read the size bytes
                            dataInputStream.readFully(b, 0, 2);
                            size = (((((int) b[0]) & BYTEMASK) << BYTESHIFT) | (((int) b[1]) & BYTEMASK));
                            LOGGER.trace("Setting size to: " + size);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        if (this.shouldTerminate) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            Iterator<ActiveSocket> it = activeSockets.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                ActiveSocket activeSocket = it.next();
                Socket socket = activeSocket.getSocket();
                LOGGER.warn(FormatData.formatStack(ex));
                synchronized (socket) {
                    socket.notify();
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Is `SwitchChannel` abstract? Does `SwitchChannel` has own implementation of `blockUntilGetMessageLength`?

Comment: SwitchChannel is an abstract class.  I had to move the blockUntilGetMessageLength() from SwitchChannel to the ActiveSocket class and there is where my problem lies.

Comment: `ActiveSocket` also abstract?

Comment: No, ActiveSocket is not an abstract class.

Comment: see my edit, hope it will help you, but its only one way in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java **does not support multiple inheritances** because it causes more problems than it solves. Instead Java
**supports multiple interface inheritance**, which allows an object to inherit many method signatures from
different interfaces with the condition that the inheriting object must implement those inherited methods.

My suggestion to use Interfaces instead and you can easily solve your problem

Example:

**BlockUntilGetMessageLengthItf.java**

```
 public interface BlockUntilGetMessageLengthItf {
  public int blockUntilGetMessageLength();
 }
```

**ActiveSocket.java**

```
public class ActiveSocket{

public ActiveSocket(BlockUntilGetMessageLengthItf ref) {
    // call local
    blockUntilGetMessageLength();

    // call to AccSysChannel  
    ref.blockUntilGetMessageLength();
}

private int blockUntilGetMessageLength(){
    // ....
    return 0;
}
}
```

**AccSysChannel.ajva**

```
public class AccSysChannel extends SwitchChannel implements BlockUntilGetMessageLengthItf{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AccSysChannel().init();
}

private void init() {

    BlockUntilGetMessageLengthItf ref  = this;

    new ActiveSocket(ref);      

}

@Override
public int blockUntilGetMessageLength() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Maxim, if you don't mind another question it would be appreciated.  I ran into a problem whereby there is NO MAIN() in the AccSysChannel class.  Consequently, is there another way to initialize the @Override method, blockUntilGetMessageLength()?  I tried using the constructor but this created a loop in my code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As we know, in Java, we can't extend 2 classes. So here we will have to use composition.
As `AccSysChannel`  is extending `SwitchChannel`, have instance of `ActiveSocket` as an attribute of `AccSysChannel`.

Using this instance you can call `blockUntilGetMessageLength` method of `ActiveSocket` from `blockUntilGetMessageLength` method of `AccSysChannel`.

You will have to remove `@Override` annotation

Comment: As @Pranalee pointed out composition means that `@Override` doesn't apply to all the methods, remove it if you get an error. Single inheritance is a design choice in Java; IMHO the right choice, C++ inheritance can get very complex.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy...you can't.  Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.  You could use a different design pattern, maybe Decorator or something, or make `SwitchChannel` inherit from `ActiveSocket`, but you cannot have split inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but had a quick question.  I thought I read something about using a class type in the blockUntilGetMessageLength() of the AccSysChannel but it was not all that clear and thought perhaps someone might know something about that type of option?  Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure what you read.  The only thing I can think of related to Class types and methods are Generics, but that has nothing to do with inheritance or overridding.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the clarification. Just googling for solutions I thought that is what I understood.  Apparently I misunderstood what I was reading.  Thanks again.